# How can I modify this SELECT query that return to me a set of rows that contains the same data to obtain a single row?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, distinct

I am not so into database and I am working on a project that perform this **SELECT** query on an **Oracle** database:

```
 SELECT coda.desc_unita1, coda.pk_coda, coda.stato, coda.fk_tipo_doc, coda.descrizione,         
        coda.num_doc, coda.data_in as data_in, coda.indirizzamento, coda.segnalazione, coda.autorizza , coda.fornitore,
        coda.data_app, coda.motivo_rifiuto, coda.tot_fattura, coda.data_doc, coda.fk_piva_mittente, coda.fk_piva_destinatario    

        FROM (SELECT d.rag_soc1 desc_unita1, a.pk_coda, a.fk_tipo_doc, b.descrizione, a.num_doc,                
                    a.data_in, c.descrizione AS stato, a.indirizzamento, a.segnalazione ,'true' as autorizza,
                    f.rag_soc1 fornitore ,a.data_lavorazione_approvatore data_app,a.motivo_rifiuto,
                    a.tot_fattura,a.data_doc, a.fk_piva_mittente, a.fk_piva_destinatario           
                    FROM coda_rx a, tipo_documenti b, stati c, fornitori d ,aggregazioni e, fornitori f           
                    WHERE a.fk_tipo_doc = b.pk_tipo_doc AND a.fk_piva_mittente = d.pk_piva 
                          AND e.piva_destinatario = f.pk_piva AND a.fk_stato = c.pk_stato
                          AND b.pk_tipo_doc = 9 AND A.CANALE IN ('WEB','BDE')AND A.FK_STATO IN( 12)            
                          AND e.pk_coda_rif = a.pk_coda AND A.NUM_DOC=e.NUM_DOC_PADRE AND e.PIVA_MITTENTE=A.FK_PIVA_DESTINATARIO            
                          AND e.tipo_doc in (0,3) ORDER BY A.PK_CODA) coda
```

This query return to me some records (not a single one but more than one) that contains **all the same data**, something like this:

```
COMPANY SRL 70028   PARKING 9   FATTURA 2222211111  26-MAG-15           true    COMPANY SRL                 01392380547 05779711000
COMPANY SRL 70028   PARKING 9   FATTURA 2222211111  26-MAG-15           true    COMPANY SRL                 01392380547 05779711000
COMPANY SRL 70028   PARKING 9   FATTURA 2222211111  26-MAG-15           true    COMPANY SRL                 01392380547 05779711000
COMPANY SRL 70028   PARKING 9   FATTURA 2222211111  26-MAG-15           true    COMPANY SRL                 01392380547 05779711000
COMPANY SRL 70028   PARKING 9   FATTURA 2222211111  26-MAG-15           true    COMPANY SRL                 01392380547 05779711000
```

What can I modify this query to obtain a single row from the previous returned rows set?, so I need to obtain something like this:

```
COMPANY SRL 70028   PARKING 9   FATTURA 2222211111  26-MAG-15           true    COMPANY SRL                 01392380547 05779711000
```

Reading the SQL documentation it seems to me that I can do it using the **DISTINCT** operation, or am I missing something? Can you help me to fix this query?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT removes duplicated rows from the result-set.

Comment: I would make two suggestions to your coding style. First use an alias that somewhat represents the table. Simply using a, b, c is a pain to deal with (especially when your code seems to be using as little white space as possible) because you have to parse the table list to figure out what is what. Also, you should use the ANSI-92 style joins as they are far less prone to error (and are far easier to read).

Comment: If you have duplicates, maybe it means the SELECT is not correct ( you should do subselect instead of a Join, or Exists ?). Of course, a distinct will in fact solve the symptoms ... But the root cause is probably in the select. Hard to say without more data.

Comment: @SeanLange I know but the code is not mine, I found it into a very old legacy application on wich I am working on and I can't change it because it could imply into a very hard and long refactoring work...and we have not the time :-(

Comment: @guigui42 the select is correct, it is a long depressing story...it is a very old legacy application that come out of some evil mind...we have to do a fix...it is pretty horrible, I know...but we can't change the project structure...too much works...

Comment: Well actually you are probably going to take the time either way. trying to decipher this type of thing is a serious pain to deal with. You have to ask the business if they don't allow for the time to fix it now, when can they schedule the time to fix it? It is a case of "do you want this right or right now?". Most people in business are reasonable enough to allow some flexibility when met with this paradox.

Comment: @SeanLange Solved with the SELECT DISTINCT...if it depends by me I erase all this project and I begin from 0 using Spring !!! But I can't: this business say to me: use a fix...the rows obtained from the query are alwayse equals, select one...so DISTINCT and amen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple "group by" will do the trick:

Your current resultset (quick example):

```
select 'COMPANY SRL' desc_unita1 , 
        70078 as pk_coda,
        'PARKING 9' stato
 from dual 
connect by level < 5 ; 

        DESC_UNITA1    PK_CODA STATO
        ----------- ---------- --------- 
    COMPANY SRL      70078 PARKING 9 
    COMPANY SRL      70078 PARKING 9 
    COMPANY SRL      70078 PARKING 9 
    COMPANY SRL      70078 PARKING 9
```

Adding the GROUP BY clause:

```
select desc_unita1,pk_coda,stato
from
(
select 'COMPANY SRL' desc_unita1 , 70078 as pk_coda, 'PARKING 9' stato
from dual
connect by level < 5
)
group by desc_unita1,pk_coda,stato; 

DESC_UNITA1    PK_CODA STATO
----------- ---------- ---------
COMPANY SRL      70078 PARKING 9
```

Is this what you are expecting as result ?